# How can I implement multi-language support in my C++ project?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, multilingual, hebrew

I'll give a small explanation of my project and my problem:
I have a big C++ project (Old project) which is built on WINAPI with MFC/ATL and DirectX 9 (Windows).
My project is separated to 8 solutions which are 7 Servers and a Client.
The Project uses CString, TCHAR and char*, uses Multi-Byte Character Set.
I would like to add RTL and LTR support for multi language purpose.

My problem:

1. The source uses CodePage
2. The source uses CString class for String manipulations.
3. there is a chat system which add a character at a time to CString class
4. there are functions like:
   void func(TCHAR* str)
   { int x = strlen(str); }
5. if I type in Hebrew inside client (I set CodePage to 1255), Client render the text as Hebrew, but the string itself shows as [image: this]

My questions:

1. How can I get rid of the codepage so I can use multi languages freely?
2. I was able to fix RTL by playing with Offset, but when there is a mix of RTL and LTR in the same string I have a problem, how can I fix that ?
3. How can I fix the string watch in the debugger to display text as the right language?

Things worth mentioning:

- I am aware that it's a difficult and huge task to do.
- I know there is a lib for that called ICU, but I don't know if it's even possible to implement and use with the current situation, if you can explain to me how to implement it, I would be appreciate it.

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: `#define _UNICODE`, `#define UNICODE`. Fix the errors. Done.

Comment: do I need to change the Use Multibyte Charset to Unicode?

Comment: If you don't use Unicode, and use some ANSI page instead, you have support for only one language. For the 1255 codepage for example, you can only display the common Latin characters (0..127) and Hebrew. Same goes for 1252, for example (Latin + accented West European). And this works only on machines with the default codepage set the same as the intended target language, not on others (eg try displaying a ANSI-1255 Hebrew text file on a West European computer in Notepad, you will get something like in your pic). And unfortunately the codepage can only be set for the system, not for each app.

Comment: You are not using pure C++.  The C++/CLI has the `CString` class, C++ doesn't.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews `CString` is a class in ATL/MFC, it is not part of C++/CLI. You might be thinking of `System::String` instead

Comment: Windows supports UTF-8 now.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou Yes, That's why I want to get rid of the CodePage. or else I will have to make so many adjustments and checks for RTL languages.
As for the unicode, I would love to use Unicode, but I don't know what's the procedure for it, what should I pay attention to, what do I do in case of char* or TCHAR, strlen, etc..

Comment: There's no magic bullet, you must move to unicode. Follow IInspectable advice. Also get rid of TCHAR, replace by wchar_t. CString can be kept but make sure it's not using ANSI overloads. Track all "blah" and replace by L"blah". Things *will* break, it's a lot of work, but the compiler is here to help you get rid of *all* ANSI code.

Comment: Make sure to also `#define _CSTRING_DISABLE_NARROW_WIDE_CONVERSION` to inhibit generation of conversion constructors. Compile again, and fix all the errors the compiler reports. Make sure to **not ever** use a cast in an attempt to fix the issues.

Comment: @SimonMourier  I heard that using wchar_t is bad practice because of Linux and Windows difference in its size.

Comment: @iinspectable can you please explain that more to me ? I understood what you mean but not entirely, should I change my charset to Unicode in the properties ? Add this define in the preprocessor ? What do you mean by never use a cast ? I hope you can help me with that, Thank you a lot!

Comment: You never talked about linux. The question is marked [mfc] and [winapi]. Being cross platform just adds to the nightmare. To make it short, getting rid of codepage encoding means using Unicode. You can use Unicode with UTF16 (wchar_t) or UTF8. UTF8 can be stored in one byte arrays but Windows only support this encoding (UTF8 stored as ANSI sort of) in specific places. That doesn't change the fact you should move to Unicode and whatever encoding you choose, there's lots of work ahead, and prior to that a lot of reading and understanding what all this encoding's fuss about

Comment: @SimonMourier yes I know and I am not planning on going cross platform anytime soon Ofcourse, but if one day it will happen I still think it would be bad to use wchar_t, I think now there are wchar8_t and some other alternative that are safer to use, I don’t remember them all. And yes there are lots of work that’s why I try to get a gist of where to start and how because I am lost in it.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, you should change the character encoding to Unicode (which sets the preprocessor symbols `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` for you). Otherwise you will have to set those symbols manually, ideally on the command line when invoking the compiler. `_CSTRING_DISABLE_NARROW_WIDE_CONVERSION` needs to be manually defined, again, either through the IDE or on the command line.

Comment: wchar8_t won't do much more than char for most APIs on Windows, it generally won't help for Unicode support. If you (try to) plan for the future, then define your own MYCHAR thing, use wchar_t for it on Windows, and you'll see later for other systems.

Comment: In between changing an application to use Unicode and porting an MFC application to an OS that doesn't even expose an API (like Linux) lies an ocean of complexity. Introducing Unicode to an application is trivially simple in comparison. While you are struggling with the basics of Unicode in Windows, you need to be considerate and don't even think about cross-platform support. That *"one day"* is well over a decade away given your current skill set.

Comment: @IInspectable Hey, if I have a char, TCHAR, LPCTSTR, etc.. should I replace them to wchar_t ? or should I leave them as TCHAR/LPCTSTR ?
and what about std::string ?

Comment: IIRC DX9 don't support UTF8, or maybe I am wrong?

Comment: DX9 used COM. As such it uses COM's string type (`BSTR`) which contains UTF-16 encoded text. That matches Windows' native character encoding. As for your code you should replace all occurrences of generic-text mappings (such as `TCHAR`) with explicit wide character string types and functions (e.g. `wchar_t`, `std::wstring`, `CStringW`, `wcslen()`, ...) and use UTF-16 throughout. That doesn't implement multi-language support by itself, but enables the application to have it added in a second step.

Answer (score 0):

> 2. I was able to fix RTL by playing with Offset, but when there is a mix of RTL and LTR in the same string I have a problem, how can I fix that ?

The `RTL` setting is applied to the entire control, as far as I know.

One way to mix those is to render HTML, as in here: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir.

[RichEdit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/rich-edit-controls) control?